# How to rotate text while writing it on image using win2D.uwp in C#?

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I am using win2d.uwp nuget package for adding water mark on a image and then save it. Like this

```
drawingSession.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
drawingSession.DrawText("Sample Text", x, y, txtColor, canvasTxtFormat);
```

Everything is working fine. I want to rotate this text while writing it on the image and I am having a hard time finding help regarding this online.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `Matrix3x2.CreateRotation` to rotate your text. For example, the following code rotates the text in **90 degrees clockwise**. Don't forget to specify the *center point* as in the second parameter.

```
drawingSession.Transform *= Matrix3x2.CreateRotation((float)Math.PI / 2, new Vector2(_dimension / 2));
drawingSession.DrawText("Sample Text", x, y, txtColor, canvasTxtFormat);
```